# Javascript regExp - replace function should decide not to replace matched string to let other parenthesized submatch string work with a match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is a very simple example of what I want to do.
Suppose I have this code:

```
function myReplaceFunction(match, p1, p2) {
    // If "(fooball:)" got a match
    if (p1) {
        // Just some condition. This one is stupid, but you get the idea.
        if (match === "football:") {
            // Don't do anything. Can I not replace from function?
            return match;
        }
    } else if (p2) { // If "(ball:)" got a match
        if (match === "ball:") {
            return "step:";
        }
    }
};

var regexp = /(football:)|(ball:)/g;
var originalString = 'something football: something';
var newString = originalString.replace(regexp, myReplaceFunction);
console.log(newString);
```

> The result: "something football: something"
>
> I want: "something footstep: something"

After (football:) gets a match, my function should decide not to replace "football:" with anything, BUT I do want the second parenthesized submatch string "ball:" to replace "ball:" with "step:", so the result would be "something footstep: something".

I need to give a (ball:) chance to work with the original string too...
Can I achieve this? If question is unclear, please ask, I'll explain.
Thank you!

Comment: What should happen when the string "something ball: something" is handled?  Will there always be a prefix portion attached to "ball:"?

Comment: "something ball: something" should become "something step: something". So, prefix portion "foot" will not always be there.

Comment: Ok, so if you're always just replacing `ball:` with step, regardless of any possible prefix, then `s.replace(/([\w+])(ball):/,"$1step:");` might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks.
But, it's not replacing it with a "step" in a real case scenario with just a constant value. 
The "step" is a dynamically generated/retrieved word that should be generated in the function, so I can't just replace it with constant literal... I do need a function. And "football" sometimes will be replaced, so that "ball:" won't get a chance to work with original string and sometimes "football:" won't pass condition, then "ball:" should work with a match.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**: Changed based on your link in comment.

Give this a try. I did build a fast lookup from `displayName` to `systemName` to use:

```
var fieldNames = [
        { displayName: "Sender", systemName: "from_field"},
        { displayName: "Receiver(addressee)", systemName: "to_field"},
        { displayName: "Author", systemName: "author_id_field"}
    ],
    regex = /(?:#?"?)([^":]+)(?:"?):/i,
    map = {
        "Sender": "from_field",
        "Receiver(addressee)": "to_field",
        "Author": "author_id_field"
    };

var test = [
    '#"Sender":',
    '"Sender":',
    'Sender:',
    '#"Receiver(addressee)":',
    '"Receiver(addressee)":',
    'Receiver(addressee):',
    '#"Unknown":'
];

for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
    var systemName = test[i].replace(regex, function(match, p1) {
       if (p1) return map[p1] || p1;
    });
    console.log("Display[%s] = System[%s]", test[i], systemName);
}
// output:
// Display[#"Sender":] = System[from_field] 
// Display["Sender":] = System[from_field] 
// Display[Sender:] = System[from_field] 
// Display[#"Receiver(addressee)":] = System[to_field] 
// Display["Receiver(addressee)":] = System[to_field] 
// Display[Receiver(addressee):] = System[to_field]
// Display[#"Unknown":] = System[Unknown]
```

If the `displayname` being matched isn't known (_i.e. in the lookup map), it simply returns it as is.

Comment: Thank you. This is close. But, let's change example a little, so you'll understand exactly what I need.

Forget about my example please.
'anything' would be any characters in my next example.
So, I want to replace '#"anything":' with some dynamically retrieved word. But, in some cases it should not change '#"anything":' and let other parenthesized submatch strings work with original string.
If '#"anything":' passed condition in the replace function and is replaced with dynamically generated word - great.

Comment: However, if it didn't pass the condition, then I want to work with '"anything":'(without #). If '"anything":' passes condition - great. However, if it didn't pass the condition, then I want to work with 'anything:'. And then it finally will be replaced.

Ah, it's really hard to explain, but thank you very much for patience.

Comment: So, not sure I'm following.  A potential string is `#"anything":`, including the double-quotes.  What other substrings would you be matching in that, other than the text between the quotes?

And, in some cases (some _condition_) you want to leave `#"anything"` alone, meaning you don't want to replace it with anything; but if other substring matches should be allowed to work, what would those substring matches be?

Comment: `if (p2 == 'ball')` When the regex matches, `p2` is always ball. :)

Comment: David, please take a look at this question where I described with code samples exactly what is my goal.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154820/javascript-regexp-replace-function-should-decide-not-to-replace-matched-string

Thank you again!

Comment: @JoeSmith looks like the same question. Why did you duplicate it? It's definitely more explanatory with actual code; but you could have edited your original question here, too.