# Javascript Regexp - replace function should decide not to replace matched string to let other parenthesized submatch strings work with a match

Tags: javascript, regex, string

This is fairly simple example, what I want is this: if replace function decides not to replace a 'match' - every other parenthesized submatch string: '(".+?":)' or '([^\s]+?:)' should work on this match also and not skip it only because the first submatch string got a match on that.

Simple example, please take a look:

```
var fieldNames = [
    { displayName: "Sender", systemName: "from_field"},
    { displayName: "Receiver(addressee)", systemName: "to_field"},
    { displayName: "Author", systemName: "author_id_field"}
];

var query = 'AND (ENTITY(Company),OR(Sender:john, Receiver(addressee):john),OR(#"Receiver(addressee)":Tanaka),OR(#"Abracadabra":Phil)) OR Author:Stan';

// What I want to retrieve as a result:
// 'AND (ENTITY(Company),OR(from_field:john, to_field:john),OR(to_field:Tanaka),OR(#"Abracadabra":Phil)) OR author_id_field:Stan'

// I want to:
// Replace '#"displayName":' with 'systemName:'
// Replace '"displayName":' with 'systemName:'
// Replace 'displayName:' with 'systemName:'
regexp = /(#".+?":)|(".+?":)|([^\s]+?:)/gi;

var newQuery = query.replace(regexp, replaceDisplayName);
console.log('Result:');
console.log(newQuery);

function replaceDisplayName(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    console.log("match: " + match);
    var potentialDisplayName;
    if (p1) {
        // Get the word(s) inside: '#"displayName":' -> get 'displayName'
        potentialDisplayName = match.substring(2, match.length - 2);
    } else if (p2) {
        // Get the word(s) inside: '"displayName":' -> get 'displayName'
        potentialDisplayName = match.substring(1, match.length - 2);
    } else if (p3) {
        // Get the word(s) inside: 'displayName:' -> get 'displayName'
        potentialDisplayName = match.substring(0, match.length - 1);
    }

    console.log('potentialDisplayName: ' + potentialDisplayName);
    var systemName = getFieldNameByDisplayName(potentialDisplayName);
    console.log('found systemName: ' + systemName);

    var newStringValue = systemName ? systemName + ":" : match;
    return newStringValue;
};

function getSystemNameByDisplayName(displayName) {

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        if (fieldNames[i].displayName.toLowerCase() === displayName.toLowerCase()) {
            return fieldNames[i].systemName;
        }
    }

    return null;
};
```

Result:

> 'AND (ENTITY(Company),OR(Sender:john,
>   to_field:john),OR(#"Receiver(addressee)":Tanaka),OR(#"Abracadabra":Phil))
>   OR author_id_field:Stan'

Result that I want:

> 'AND (ENTITY(Company),OR(from_field:john,
>   to_field:john),OR(to_field:Tanaka),OR(#"Abracadabra":Phil)) OR
>   author_id_field:Stan'

The issue is that for example the first match would be:
'(ENTITY(Company),OR(Sender:'
This value is not a 'displayName', so no systemName will be found and I'll get no replacement. BUT I want 'Sender:' still be replaced with 'to_field'. But, this whole match would be skipped because the first submatch string '(#".+?":)' already worked with it, so it doesn't give a chance for other submatch strings: '(".+?":)' and '([^\s]+?:)' to work with it.

**Thank you for your time, any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. I did build a fast lookup from `displayName` to `systemName` to use:

```
var fieldNames = [
        { displayName: "Sender", systemName: "from_field"},
        { displayName: "Receiver(addressee)", systemName: "to_field"},
        { displayName: "Author", systemName: "author_id_field"}
    ],
    regex = /(?:#?"?)([^":]+)(?:"?):/i,
    map = {
        "Sender": "from_field",
        "Receiver(addressee)": "to_field",
        "Author": "author_id_field"
    };

var test = [
    '#"Sender":',
    '"Sender":',
    'Sender:',
    '#"Receiver(addressee)":',
    '"Receiver(addressee)":',
    'Receiver(addressee):',
    '#"Unknown":'
];

for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
    var systemName = test[i].replace(regex, function(match, p1) {
       if (p1) return map[p1] || p1;
    });
    console.log("Display[%s] = System[%s]", test[i], systemName);
}
// output:
// Display[#"Sender":] = System[from_field] 
// Display["Sender":] = System[from_field] 
// Display[Sender:] = System[from_field] 
// Display[#"Receiver(addressee)":] = System[to_field] 
// Display["Receiver(addressee)":] = System[to_field] 
// Display[Receiver(addressee):] = System[to_field]
// Display[#"Unknown":] = System[Unknown]
```

If the `displayname` being matched isn't known (_i.e. in the lookup map), it simply returns it as is.